# JQuery `live()` and `submit()` problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna do something like this, but this one looks like happing for infinite times.

```
$("form").live("submit", function() { 

    if($(this).attr('action') != "ajax"){
        $(this).submit();
return true; // even i do this!! but form is NOT submited!!
}

else { /* doing the ajax stuff! */ }
});
```

in Chrome and Firefox  after a while the form gets submitted, something like 10seconds and in IE it crashes !

I know when i say form.submit means that i am submitting this and get called function again and again, how can i avoid this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By fring [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) again, which bubbles back to the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler, you're causing an infinite loop, instead you want to call the native [`form.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit) method here, like this:

```
$("form").live("submit", function() { 
  if(this.action != "ajax") {
    this.submit();
  }
  else { /* doing the ajax stuff! */ }
});
```

Also [`.action` is a native DOM property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.action), you can access it that way...not need for the jQuery overhead here.

Comment: Just worked like a charm! Thanks Nick *clever!* just wondering what is the difference of Jquery `submit()` and native, and how the first time the native `submit()` will be handled by `.live` ? thanks

Comment: @Omeid - the native submit method doesn't trigger jQuery event handlers :)

Comment: @Nick - how this happens the first time ? or the JQuery `submit()` submit is binded to form on load !?

Comment: @Omeid - Initially the submit *even* fires, this is separate from the `submit()` *method* :)

Comment: @nick, thanks for answer but `alert(this.action);` Says `[Object]` not the value of action attribute, and when i tried that here http://jsfiddle.net/mZq2m/1/ First i thought the problem is with Native `this` and JQuery but that is even same for Javascript with no JQuery.

Comment: @Omeid - is it possible you have an input named `action`?

Comment: @nick, yeah i do! never though of that!

Comment: When I do `$("form").live("submit", function() {});` I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`?? Maybe it's my jQuery version? 1.10.2